# transform scaleing down makes image blurry

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, blurry

I try to make a little zoom effect on hover for some products. For that I scale the container of the image down to 95% and scale it too 100% on hover:

However the image scaled down apears blurry . I tried different solutions given in other Questions about this topic, like: backface-visibility, blur(0), translateZ. But nothing seems to change anything.

Is there a way to make this prettier or is this as good as it can get?

```css
.container {
 transform: scale(0.95);
 transition: transform 70ms ease-in;
  float: left;
}

.container:hover {
 transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="https://s28.postimg.org/kagu55chp/csm_632san_Amalfi_Pearl_ca02784e51.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="container">
<img src="https://s24.postimg.org/cdecsntlx/csm_594san_Amalfi_Silver_bbb138a25a.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS to your `img` element (Not a safe hack cross-browser-wise):

```
img {
   image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; /* Firefox */
   image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges; /* Opera */
   image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
   image-rendering: crisp-edges;
   -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor; /* IE (non-standard property) */
}
```

Snippet below:

```css
.container {
  transform: scale(.95);
  transition: transform 70ms ease-in;
  float: left;
}
.container:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}
img {
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; /* Firefox */
  image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges; /* Opera */
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor; /* IE (non-standard property) */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s28.postimg.org/kagu55chp/csm_632san_Amalfi_Pearl_ca02784e51.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/cdecsntlx/csm_594san_Amalfi_Silver_bbb138a25a.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Alternative 1:** to avoid dimension altering properties, something like `translate` on `img`:

```css
.container {
  transition: transform 70ms ease-in;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.container:hover img {
  transform: translate(0, -3px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s28.postimg.org/kagu55chp/csm_632san_Amalfi_Pearl_ca02784e51.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/cdecsntlx/csm_594san_Amalfi_Silver_bbb138a25a.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Alternative 2:** `box-shadow`:

```css
.container {
  transition: transform 70ms ease-in;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.container:hover img {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #888888;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s28.postimg.org/kagu55chp/csm_632san_Amalfi_Pearl_ca02784e51.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://s24.postimg.org/cdecsntlx/csm_594san_Amalfi_Silver_bbb138a25a.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Props for mentioning "-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;" but I don't think that's a CSS standard we can rely upon. As issue 19 of the CSS Image Values document states (https://www.w3.org/TR/css4-images/) we currently have no control of how the browser does its interpolation.

Comment: While it makes it a bit better in IE I dont see any changes in Crome and in Firefox its different, but cant tell that this is better or worse :) Your alternative however I do like. Instead of zooming the image just raise it by 3 px gives the same feeling.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree, I'm positive it doesn't get much better than this hack though. I suggested an alternative with `translate` to avoid the img dimension altering. Firefox (although a bit weird yes, but it's not blur but more like some minimal pixel async) is picking up the hack fine on mine, Chrome isn't. This has been a widespread issue for years and still is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue runs in pixel interpolation: http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-interpolation.htm

When an image is resized, the pixels must be adjusted. By shrinking, pixels are averaged and reduced. By enlarging, pixels are added and averages between pixels fill the gaps.

Please use an image editor like Photoshop or Gimpshop to resize the image, as an image program is better designed for this than a web browser.

On that note, certain percentages work better than others when it comes to browsers handling the interpolation. I've noticed it to typically be those on each quarter: 25%, 50%, 75% reduction and 125%, 150%, 175% enlargements tend to be handled better than other numbers (like 95% or 73%, etc.).

Comment: Yea normaly I would use an image editor as you suggested (Or just image magick and create the needed size on the server). But as I want it as a zoom effect in the frontend this is not possible. I mean.. I have an idea for a dirty solution that could work: creating 2 images, 95% and 100% and using the 95% image as background with background-size: cover. Then on hover change the backgroundimage too 100% and change the width and high of the div with transform: width 70ms, height 70ms. That could work.. but would make the client load 2 images

Comment: Robin Williams in her book "The Non-Designers Design Book" suggested that if you want to build visual contrast - whether interactive or static, make it big. For example, putting fonts of the same family just a few points apart cause strain on the eye while large point changes support the flow of content better. I'm not suggesting you change your design, but maybe consider how only a 5% zoom actually helps the user.